# What's wrong with the following Scala code?

Tags: scala, filtering

```
val x = "pizseagtsgevlvwpbshxfwbjijtmslkufgofretehjgpcdedstydokejsnrccnkbruawgjmemfqhwmhjsykrejmmexgrsdlwtaybtnhfcapsylopkthboqkvicgwrvycphqnulnjgfgjlqnhdyfwweyifpxyxrvpnshjrrkmkwrvjjssublanosljhqhppmewuidyqblfcjzkwbhqlljvvcjqthbkpcoquepqzcvbkdlhufbkpiyaqbfblexry"
val y = "pizseagtsgevlvwpbshxfwbjijtmslkufgofretehjgpcdedstydokejsnrccnkbruawgjmemfqhwmhjsykrejmmexgrsdlwtaybtnhfcapsylopkthboqkvicgcjkyxxubpbqcycioryppydvmwubupxrjlwrwujsiimvpbgkdugjbpqtodgbzzpsduewwovwlfrarfiuaztmmohagkjzzdcnjytamlzpwpfmhlgsdlwfbluxqllcjxbltbrlhgngvtxyksllhfhhzknesqggfazixcotpwwbjenbglhcbnhgjgyimfvfbcezatumthzrqtvdyirxulfhwylbdhkibmiagdgeerriszbnfxmoxgabaxkgkydrnrrbatjbavwdxjqirqivqweqdxeiiotbfidiemakmzbwszgrgekrlalsmbplumxeqmfrulddmbactyuhdljlhhjvxumpkyyzouybtwxtoyiffrderzmztkcdsbhcij"
val xy = (x zip y).filter{ case (a,b) => (a==b) }.map{case (a,b) => a}.mkString
```

I expect the xy will be

> pizseagtsgevlvwpbshxfwbjijtmslkufgofretehjgpcdedstydokejsnrccnkbruawgjmemfqhwmhjsykrejmmexgrsdlwtaybtnhfcapsylopkthboqkvicg

but it is

> pizseagtsgevlvwpbshxfwbjijtmslkufgofretehjgpcdedstydokejsnrccnkbruawgjmemfqhwmhjsykrejmmexgrsdlwtaybtnhfcapsylopkthboqkvicgydwrsjzpdlblr

Somehow, the filtering does not work as expected. Anything I missed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`filter` does not stop after the first `false` but continues to traverse the remaining collection. Those additional characters appear later in both string at the same position. What you want instead of filter is `takeWhile`:

```
val xy = (x zip y).takeWhile{ case (a,b) => (a==b) }.map{case (a,b) => a}.mkString
```